# Java Fx2.x : LineChart setStrokeDashArray

Tags: css, javafx-2, linechart

I have a LineChart and I can plot with different Stroke Dash Array but I can't plot as dotted such as

```
-fx-stroke-dash-array: 0.1,5.0;
```

or

```
-fx-stroke-dash-array: 0.8,8.0;
```

Any reason for this? When I use these settings it plots as solid line.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [cssref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

`-fx-stroke-dash-array` has a type "size [size ]+", so it doesn't need commas inside.

I tried on a separate application, not related to charts. And

```
-fx-stroke-dash-array: 0.1,5.0;
```

shows a solid line, while

```
-fx-stroke-dash-array: 0.1 5.0;
```

shows a dotted line.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your suggestion